# How to apply a WP child theme to a different site? -- I copied files and it didn't work

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have the twentyeleven theme on this site: http://richardclunan.com/ -- with some changes -- so I have a twentyeleven-child theme.

They're smallish changes -- things like the font and the font size.

I would like to make the same changes to this site: http://richardclunan.net/

…I logged into my hosting account and copied twentyeleven-child from the richardclunan.com theme folder to the richardclunan.net theme folder…

…but the changes didn't appear on richardclunan.net

-- Is there something else I need to do to make this happen?

-- Or is it not possible to make the relevant changes in this way -- copying across the folder and files -- should I be doing this a different way?

(I'm not a techie, and might not understand phraseology unless the 'what' and the 'where' is spelled out :)

Answer (score 2):

You must change the theme in your  http://richardclunan.net/ wordpress admin. 
Inside your site admin, go to Aparence->Themes and select your theme.

Comment: thanks. that works. the stackexchange system is telling me i can accept the answer in 9 mins -- so i'll drop back to do that.